Mi assertTrue (el ultimo del codigo) provoca que mi test falle, pero el archivo se descarga exitosamente
Tengo este código de un test donde al final cuando descarga el archivo de la búsqueda de Albert Einstein, lo descarga bien en la carpeta por default, mas sin embargo al llegar a ese ultimo assertTrue(downloadedFile.exists(), "The PDF file was not downloaded."); falla el test y el archivo se descargó exitosamente.
    public void testDownloadPdf() {
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
    assertTrue(mainPage.state().isDisplayed(), "Main page is not displayed");

    mainPage.search("Albert Einstein");

    ArticlePage articlePage = new ArticlePage();
    assertTrue(articlePage.state().isDisplayed(), "Article page is not displayed");

    articlePage.downloadAsPdf();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File downloadedFile = new File(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER + "/" + DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
    assertTrue(downloadedFile.exists(), "The PDF file was not downloaded.");
    }


Yo verificaría que el valor de DOWNLOAD_FOLDER + "/" + DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME me de la ruta del archivo correcta (si es relativa, ojo con cuál es la carpeta actual cuando corre el test). También verificaría que el usuario bajo el que corre el proceso de test tenga permisos a dicha carpeta y archivo.
